# Join tables based on most recent date for each record

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble joining tables on dates that are most most recent for each row.  I've created some dummy data below that is similar to what I'm dealing with.  Essentially I have a master listing of dates, and I want to be able to see the closest date (without exceeding that date) in a corresponding table.

For example, table A (MY_DATES) will have a list of unique dates.  table B (BACKUPS) will have a list of dates that backups were completed.  I want to show all dates in MY_DATES and the most recent backup date for that date based on data in BACKUPS.

Here are some dummy tables:

### MY_DATES

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/01/2020 |
| 01/02/2020 |
| 01/03/2020 |
| 01/04/2020 |
| 01/05/2020 |

### BACKUPS

| DATE | USER |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 151821 |
| 01/10/2020 | 151821 |

The query results that I'm going for should be similar to this:

### Query Results (most recent backup for each date)

| DATE | MOST_RECENT_BACKUP |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/02/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/03/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/04/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/05/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/06/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/07/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/08/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/09/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 01/10/2020 | 01/10/2020 |
| 01/11/2020 | 01/10/2020 |
| 01/12/2020 | 01/10/2020 |

If I select all from dates and join on backups I only get data for those specific dates:

```
select
    d.*
    ,b.DATE MOST_RECENT_BACKUP
    ,b.USER
from
    MY_DATES d
    left join BACKUPS b on (d.date = b.date) --doesn't work
    --left join BACKUPS b on (d.date <= b.date) --doesn't work either
;
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this but I can't figure out how to approach it.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `OUTER APPLY` is like the `LEFT JOIN` that you tried, but it allows you to join to an inline view AND it allows you to refer to columns from previously joined tables in the `WHERE` clause of that inline view.

Using `OUTER APPLY` you can use the `WHERE` clause to find all the backups that occurred on or before each date, use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort them by backup date latest-to-earliest, and then use the `FETCH FIRST` clause to just get the first one in the sorted list (i.e., the latest backup).

```
SELECT d.*, b.DATE most_recent_backup
FROM   my_dates d
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT b.date
              FROM backups b 
              WHERE b.date <= d.date 
              ORDER BY b.date DESC
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) b
```

You can also do this with `NOT EXISTS` if you aren't on a version of Oracle that supports `OUTER APPLY`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT d.*, b.DATE most_recent_backup
FROM   my_dates d
LEFT JOIN backups b ON b.date <= d.date
WHERE ( 
    -- Either the backup date is NULL (this happens if the LEFT JOIN
    -- found no backups earlier than the given date)
    b.date IS NULL
    OR  
    -- Or there is a backup later than the row backup we are looking at.
    -- The LEFT JOIN condition joins each date to ALL the backups that
    -- happened on or before that date.  This condition excludes
    -- every backup for a given date except for the most recent one.
    -- If the backup is not the most recent backup on or before a 
    -- given date, there will exist a later backup that is also on
    -- or before that same date.
    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'later backup that is earlier than date'
                     FROM   backups b2
                     WHERE  b2.date <= d.date
                     AND    b2.date > b.date )
      )
```

Comment: thank you very much for both of those solutions.  They both work but I found that the outer apply, while simpler to understand, was a bit slower (perhaps because it executes that function for each row) and it also does not work in all cases.  My original date sequence was from a 'Table of Dates' being returned by a custom function and for some reason when using those dates, the Outer Apply approach returns the most recent backup date for every date in my date sequence.  Only when I switch to a different date sequence (e.g. use start date + level connect by...) does it work(cont)

Comment: The second solution that you provided works as well and is extremely quick; however, I cant figure out how this works.  If you have some time, could you explain how this works?  Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Feyam I added a few comments to the query in my answer.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

if oracle11g, you can use `ignore nulls`

```sql
with tab1 as(
select to_date('20210101', 'yyyymmdd') + level - 1 dat 
  from dual 
connect by level < 20
),
tab2 as (
select to_date('20210101', 'yyyymmdd') dat from dual union all
select to_date('20210110', 'yyyymmdd') dat from dual 
)
select t1.*,
       t2.*,
       nvl(lag(t2.dat ignore nulls) over(order by t1.dat), t1.dat)
  from tab1 t1,
       tab2 t2
 where t1.dat = t2.dat(+)
;
```

@astentx
It can still get the correct result, Even the data is more unusual

```sql
with tab1 as (
select trunc(sysdate) - 100 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) - 99 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) - 9 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) - 5 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) - 4 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) - 2 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) + 10 dat from dual union all
select trunc(sysdate) + 11 dat from dual
)
,tab2 as (
select trunc(sysdate) - level dat from dual connect by level < 10--backup
)
select t1.*,
       t2.*,
       case when t1.dat = t2.dat then t2.dat  
            when t1.dat is null then null 
            else
                 lag(t2.dat ignore nulls) over(order by nvl(t1.dat, t2.dat))
       end
  from tab1 t1 full join tab2 t2 on t1.dat = t2.dat
;
```

Comment: This will not return the data if no backups were taken at specified dates.

Comment: Because there is no such dummy data,if it exists.you can use `full join and nvl()` to solve @astentx

Comment: It is not dummy data: backup was performed 5 days ago but you run the query for today and yesterday. There will be nothig joined. For full join it will require to wrap this statement with another `select` from it to filter out `null` records. So my first statement is true: *This* will not return the data if no backups were taken at specified dates. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a05e09868edb84a1d0629195e4a81fb)

Comment: @nayi224 thank you for that solution!  That works very quickly and is simple enough to remember!  This appears to be just as quick as matthewmcpeak's second solution that he provided too!